# How to gain the strength to successfully perform a pull up

Tags: pull-ups, upper-body-workout

I have very little upper body strength and stamina and have never been able to do a pull up but I'd like to be able to. When holding on to the bar hanging, my arms fully extended I'm unable to lift myself at all. I'm just kind of stuck there hanging. Are there specific exercises to target the muscles necessary to be able to do one?

I've tried jumping and slowing my descent down (basically doing a pull up in reverse) but I'm not making much progress. Is that the right path and I just need to keep at it or are there more efficient exercises that would increase the strength necessary for these?

Comment: Negatives and band-assisted pull-ups.

Comment: Lose weight. Do more pullups. Easy.